# add element to a nested array in a dictionary converting series to readable dictionary with nested arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I need to add an element to an array that is inside a dictionary, This is my code:

```py
indexes9 = []
dataInfected9 = {}
for index, value in data9.items():
    if index[0] not in indexes9:
        indexes9.append(index[0])
    dataInfected9[index[1]].append(value)
```

The data looks like this

```
{Series(32,)}
(('NSW', 'hs'), 1539) (('NSW', 'blood'), 70) (('NSW', 'hsid'), 50) .... (('QLD', 'hs'), 186)
```

And should look like this:

```
dataInfected9 = {
    "hs":[1539, ..., 186],
    "blood":[70, ..., 90],
    ....
    }, 
    
)
indexes=['NSW', ..., 'QLD']
```

The problem is this code `dataInfected9[index[1]].append(value)` is not working, is ginign me the error:

```
File ... line 84... 
dataInfected9[index[1]].append(value)
KeyError: 'hs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
dataInfected9 = {}
indexes = set()                     #Using set to prevent dups.
for (k, v), n in data9.items():
    indexes.add(k)
    dataInfected9.setdefault(v, []).append(n)
```

Comment: thanks! that worked for me, didn't know about dict.setdefault()

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this line `dataInfected9[index[1]].append(value)` isn't working is that it s trying to access the index (for example 'hr'), when it s not initially declared or initialized.

A solution for is the following, is adding the following before the problematic line :

```
if index[1] not in dataInfected9:
    dataInfected9[index[1]] = []
```

Comment: your explanation helped me to understand the other answer, yours is good but the other one is more clean

Comment: well, if it was of help then that s great. keep up the good work